# Tkinter/Canvas typeError when attempting to use keybinds

Tags: python, animation, tkinter, canvas

new to Python. I'm working on an assignment for class where the car needs to be able to speed up/slow down. When attempting to use the keybinds, I get the following typeError:
`TypeError:speedUp() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given`

I attempted placing @staticmethod before defining speedUp/slowDown, and it returned a separate error that it was not defined. I feel like I'm missing a syntax or placement issue? Any help appreciated.

```
def main():

    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title = ("Race Car")
    canvas = tk.Canvas(root, width=600, height=400, bg="white")
    canvas.pack()

    # starting at position
    x = 0
    y = 300

    def displayCar():
        # First Wheel
        canvas.create_oval(x + 10,y - 10, x + 20, y, fill="black", tags="car")
        # Second Wheel
        canvas.create_oval(x + 30, y - 10, x + 40, y, fill="black", tags="car")
        # Body
        canvas.create_rectangle(x, y - 20,x + 50,y - 10, fill="blue", tags="car")


    displayCar()

    instructions=tk.Label(root, text="To speed up the car, press the up arrow. To slow down, press the down arrow.").pack()


    # movement speed
    dx = 5
    sleeptime = 100
    width = 600


    def speedUp():
        if sleepTime>5:
            sleepTime-=20
            print("Speeding up")

    def slowDown():
            sleepTime+=20
            print("slowing down")

    canvas.bind("<Up>", speedUp)
    canvas.bind("<Down>", slowDown)
    canvas.focus_set()


    while True:
        canvas.move("car", dx,0)
        canvas.after(100)
        canvas.update()
        if x < width:
            x+=dx
        else:
            x=0
            canvas.delete("car")
            displayCar()


    canvas.mainloop()


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The methods `speedUp` and `slowDown` are always called with the `event` argument from Tkinter ([see the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.html#bindings-and-events)).
Add it to the method signature even if you don't need the value. This is the easiest way to fix it.

```py
def speedUp(event):
    if sleepTime>5:
        sleepTime-=20
        print("Speeding up")

def slowDown(event):
    sleepTime+=20
    print("slowing down")
```

(the parameter name doesn't matter)